# Can you see who initiated a clan war?

Tags: clash-of-clans

Is there any way to tell which clan member initiated a clan war? Our clan likes to be well prepared for our wars to maximize our chances of victory. Occasionally someone will start a war randomly and it is disruptive to the group as a whole. Is there anyway to tell who is starting these wars so we can ban them if they continue this behavior after a warning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently, only leaders and co-leaders can initiate wars. The clan chat will log the player who started or canceled the clan war search. If you want any more information on clan wars go to their [FAQ](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Clan_Wars_FAQ).

Comment: -1 | Yes it does display - The chat logs whenever a leader/co-leader initiate a clan war search, or cancelled it.

Comment: @aytimothy Forgot about that, so I changed my post. Feel free to edit anything that I have missed.

Comment: Oops.. Didn't realized you answered this ages ago. Anyway, switched to a +1.